# Copying file from network folder over VPN extremely slow

Tags: networking, vpn, file-transfer

My coworker and I both have the same type of laptops, connecting to the same wireless network at work. 
There is a 32GB SQL Server data file we are copying on our local machine from a network folder that we connect to it through the same VPN too. 
It took him 2 hours to copy it, it took me 13 hours to copy it.

What parameters do you think might cause this much slowness in speed?

Comment: Not related to the specific question but you may want to consider copying the file in two steps (eg. onto a USB stick and then onto the laptop) instead of spending time investigating the variable wifi connection issue. There are tonnes of things that affect it such an application streaming something on one laptop, your local connection to the internet ./ network, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on (1) your proximity to the wireless access point, (2) the wireless access point's supported protocols, (3) the supported protocols on your laptop.

For example:

- If you are farther away it may copy slower (depending)
- If your wireless access point supports 802.11ac and 802.11g and so does your coworkers' laptop, however, your laptop only support 802.11g, it will transfer at the fastest speed it supports and can find.

Comment: well that's the thing, we are given laptops with the same spec and we are sitting next to each other in the cubes.

Comment: How strange! Do you both use the same Antivirus, same firewall? Check the Resource Monitor and see what spikes up in usage when transferring.

Answer (score 0):

Are you positive both are connecting to the same VPN?

In large companies you might have different VPN entry points, very likely in different geographic locations.

If your partner connects through the US VPN and you are using a European VPN your latency will be much higher and your throughput will suffer tremendously as in your case.

Compare network conditions in both computers by pinging to several websites (if you have access to the Internet) or to the same network resources. Make several rounds of testing.

You can also check in the networking tab of the Windows Task Manager if you have the same link speed. Maybe you're connecting to a 2.4 GHz WiFi network and your partner is connecting to a 5 GHz network (usually faster).

There are many things to look for. Shame you didn't put any test results in your question.